# How to implement a tree-like data structure in rust?

Tags: pointers, rust, tree

I need to implement a tree-like data structure, in which each node possibly has 2 children, and each child node has a reference to its parent (except root node).
Here is a sketch:

```
strcut Node {
    parent:  Option< ??? >,
    child_1: Option<Box<Node>>,
    child_2: Option<Box<Node>>
}
```

As you can see I don't know what type should a parent field be. Can it be just a plain unsafe pointer? What is the proper way of implementing it?

Comment: You can make do with `Option<Rc<Node>>` and `Option<Weak<Node>>`, but some operations are more easily and efficiently implemnted with some unsafe code.

Comment: @SvenMarnach `Option<Weak>` is unecessary; `Weak` can already be empty with `Weak::new()` (with what I consider to be a design mistake, but not it's too late to fix).

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Right, and you probably also need `RefCell` inside the `Rc` to be able to do anything useful.